# MySQL: Merge ID #'s from guest and registered users

Tags: mysql

I am editing a site that contains multiple quizzes. Users can answer questions as a guest and as a registered user. In MySQL, the same user that answers questions as a guest, and then later as a registered user, is assigned a different ID using the auto-increment feature. I know that I can use point and click to merge the answers from the same participant to the same ID #, but is there a way I can do this automatically?

Comment: How will you identify the former guest with the new member? What do you do about guests who visit more than once? Why don't you assign the ID the first time someone visits the site and have a column in the table that specifies whether they are guest or member?

Comment: Hi nurdglaw! Assume that I am able to identify which guest and registered IDs match up to each other. They will have the same guest id if they login without registration multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user's IP address to link together answers they submitted as a guest and answers they submitted whilst logged in.

Comment: Thanks! Could you perhaps help me find a link where I could learn to do that?